How do I carry out an in silico PCR on a bacterial genome (target:16S rRNA)? Unable to find any bacterial genome on UCSC Genome Browser in silico PCR
I could not find any bacterial species in the drop-down list for genomes in https://genome.ucsc.edu/cgi-bin/hgPcr
Any kind of help would be appreciated. Other links for in silico PCR did not really work or perhaps I do not know the procedure well. Hopefully this query aids others in the future seeking a similar solution.
Edit: I wanted to check the primer pair 27F and 1492R which are part of Oxford Nanopore 16S library prep kit (SQK-16S024) on a bacterial genome.

Your question lacks clarity and detail : what is the purpose of the PCR ? What would you want to do with the amplicons ?

Need to check why the Oxford Nanopore 16S024 kit's primer pair (27F and 1492R) is resulting in two bands instead of a single band of 16S rRNA gene. Once I get the amplicons, there's library prep followed by sequencing on Nanopore to understand which bacteria were present in the samples of interest.

What size bands? This primer set has been found to amplify some 18s eukaryotic rRNA genes, especially when using a lower annealing temp that is more permissive to minor mismatches. TestPrime is a good in silico PCR tool, but it only runs on the Silva SSU and LSU rRNA databases (not whole genomes). https://www.arb-silva.de/search/testprime/

@MikeyC The size of the band should be around 1500 bp since these primers are for full-length V1-V9 16S region. And you are correct, I did come across literature which talk about cross-reactivity of 16S primers with eukaryotic 18S genes. I was not aware of this until now so thank you very much! I shall check out your suggestions and if you want to know, I could keep you posted, formally.

I would suggest using NCBI's Primer-BLAST tool. Formerly I would have recommended their e-PCR tool, but it has been retired. This retirement link has a lot of instructional information for how to use the tool.
You can upload your own assembly/accession, or very likely most well known species of bacteria will be in their database or in refseq.

Thank you for the response. I shall try to learn how to effectively use the Primer-BLAST. I tried it but could not follow well. In the meantime, could you give more pointers? I am supposed to upload a reference genome as template, right? I tried that with the primers but it did not work.

@RahulDhargalkar You could upload a reference genome, or you could select one of the included genomes that is in RefSeq. I'd suggest following the instructions here: https://ncbiinsights.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/2017/06/28/e-pcr-is-retiring-use-primer-blast/. I can try to add a working example later when I have more time.
